# Xcode 4.6.3 crashing after installing xcode 6 beta

Tags: xcode

I've installed Xcode 6 beta for tryout, and older 4.6.3 now crashing on start, I need it to work on enterprise app. Already tried to reinstall 4.6.3, removed 6, nothing helps.
Is there any decision for that kind of problem?

Comment: I have the same problem. Please let me know if you'll find some solution. Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo mv /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework{,-saved}
```

Comment: i've tried it but its still not working, it moves one step forward means by doing this what you have suggested it opens the xcode but it crashes again and again, please helpme to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean?

```
sudo mv /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework saved
```

or

```
sudo rm /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework saved
```

Answer (score 0):

I just made it with:

```
sudo mv /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework-saved
```