# XCode 4.6.3 crash everytime I open it on OS X 10.9.3

Tags: xcode, osx-mavericks, crash-reports

I updated Mavericks 10.9.2 to 10.9.3 and downloaded Xcode 6 beta. One of my project is still in Xcode 4.6.3. So now whenever I open this project Xcode crashes with the following pop up.

[image]

It was working fine in OS X 10.9.2. Is it OS related issue? Please help

Comment: Try it from a different account; if it works there then Xcode's preferences are messed up on the original account. You can ether deleted them  ('/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Xcode.plist') or try to fix them via an XML editor.

Comment: Any solution for this trouble? I have the same problem :(

Answer (score 8):

I had similar issue. This can be fixed using

```
`sudo mv /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework{,-saved}`
```

This will ask for system component installation and then Xcode starts working.

**I recommend to use latest version of Xcode 6.x.**

[image: Issue encountered]
[image: Additional component for Xcode 4.x]

[image: Installation process]
[image: Installing file]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

sudo mv /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework{,-saved}

Answer (score 2):

Javi Campana's answer and Iron Eagle's (
[Xcode 4.6.3 crashing after installing xcode 6 beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24035694/xcode-4-6-3-crashing-after-installing-xcode-6-beta) )
worked for me.

I believe the missing key point is running Xcode 4.6.3 directly after renaming the MobileDevice.framework.

Xcode 4.6 will then prompt you to install "Device Support" component.

Once installed, my Xcode 4.6.3 and Xcode 6 beta 2 worked again with MobileDevice.framework version 555.43 created Dec 21, 2014.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out Xcode 4.6 does not work with iTunes higher than 11.4.

Instructions how to downgrade you may find here: http://osxdaily.com/2014/10/26/downgrades-itunes-12/

Comment: Thanks for saving!!