# Xcode 5.1 crashing after installing Xcode6-beta version

Tags: xcode, xcode5, xcode5.1, xcode6

**The application "`Xcode5.1.1`" can't be opened.**

I use `x-code 5.1` to build iOS apps, now when i installed `x-code6 beta` version to implement app with swift language then `xcode 5.1` is not working. It is giving me such error- 
[image]

I use to resolve problem with [Xcode 4.6.3 crashing after installing xcode 6 beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24035694/xcode-4-6-3-crashing-after-installing-xcode-6-beta?rq=1) but not found this useful for my case.

I have tried to restart machine but it is giving same error. I googled for it but not got useful stuff. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to select different "Command line tools" in the bottom of Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations.

You can do it in your working Xcode 6.

Comment: Thanks but please let me know, how can I choose preferences when xcode is not being opened.

Comment: @Nico Xcode 6 beta isn't working too? Or you can use xcode-select: http://blog.tyreeapps.com/2013/10/using-xcode-select-and-bash-aliases.html

Answer (score 0):

After trying more I found it useful

Restart your machine then it can work, if not like my case then try below command in your `Terminal`

sudo mv /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework{,-saved}

then again restart your machine then it will ask for **installing few components of `Xcode`** so allow it, then your `Xcode 5.1.1` will work fine.